# Angular new router force components folder under root

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

I'm trying to use [angular new router](https://github.com/angular/router) in my Angular 1.5 (+ Typescript) project.

I followed the getting started manual but it forces me to have all my HTML components folder right under my root folder:

> Could not instantiate controller HomeController
>
> http://localhost:8083/components/home/home.html 404 (Not Found)

Can I change it?

My routing code is:

```
this.$router.config([
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
      { path: '/home', component: 'home' }}
]);
```

And my component is:

```
namespace app.dashboard {
    'use strict';

    class HomeController {
    }

    angular.module('app.dashboard')
        .component('home', {
            templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/components/home.html',
            controller: HomeController,
            controllerAs: 'HomeController',
            bindings: {}
        });
}
```

and my nested folder is app/dashboard/components under root path

Comment: have you tried to use some kind of template for C#/Visual studio? I know i've got this https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83 and I've got the mvc structure on VS.

Answer (score 1):

To have your html somewhere else you need to specify the templateURL like:

```
this.$router.config([
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
      { path: '/home', component: 'home' },
      { path: '/login', component: 'login', templateUrl: '/views/login' }
]);
```

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route

You can find more on [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) about rooting. under the templateUrl you can specify the file path without extension.

**UPDATE:** You want to use that specific this.$router.config? I'm asking this because you can you something like:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        // UI States, URL Routing & Mapping. For more info see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/index',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'

            });
}]);
```

And you won't need to use components, is same thing, i think, for rooting but you will need to add 'ui.router' as a dependency to your app.

Comment: I'm using templateURL in my component (I've edited my question) when I tried to add like you suggested it doesn't worked.
Also why do I need 2 line of component: 'home' ?

Comment: sry for 2 line of home I was just rushing :( I've update it:)

Comment: It's still not working and unable to retrieve my controller and still trying to open the HTML from root path components folder (I've edited my question)